# Calculated quartile category of a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as shown below

df:

```
product_x  year     total_price      total_sale
A          2016     50               200           
B          2016     200              100           
A          2017     250              250           
B          2017     1000             300           
A          2018     100              50           
B          2018     900              600
K          2016     20               300
D          2016     100              450
```

In above data frame I would like add new column called total_sale_Quartile.

Explanation to calculate total_sale_Quartile.

sort total_sale as shown below

```
50, 100, 200, 250, 300, 300, 450, 600

Q1 = 50 to 100
Q2 = 101 to 250
Q3 = 251 to 300
Q4 = 301 to 600
```

Expected output:

```
product_x  year     total_price      total_sale   total_sale_Quartile
A          2016     50               200          Q2
B          2016     200              100          Q1    
A          2017     250              250          Q2  
B          2017     1000             300          Q3   
A          2018     100              50           Q1    
B          2018     900              600          Q4
K          2016     20               300          Q3
D          2016     100              450          Q4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use, [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with optional parameter `include_lowest=True` to categorise the values from `total_sale` into `Quartiles`:

```
df['total_sale_Quartile'] = (
    pd.cut(
        df['total_sale'], bins=[50, 100, 250, 300, 600],
        labels=['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'], include_lowest=True)
)
```

OR, use [`pd.qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) if you want to categorise the column just based on the quantile ranges:

```
df['total_sale_Quartile'] = (
    pd.qcut(df['total_sale'], 4, labels=['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'])
)
```

Result:

```
# print(df)
  product_x  year  total_price  total_sale total_sale_Quartile
0         A  2016           50         200                  Q2
1         B  2016          200         100                  Q1
2         A  2017          250         250                  Q2
3         B  2017         1000         300                  Q3
4         A  2018          100          50                  Q1
5         B  2018          900         600                  Q4
6         K  2016           20         300                  Q3
7         D  2016          100         450                  Q4
```

Comment: can we get the bin values using describe function?

Comment: if we have very large values df, can we pass this bins = list(df.total_sale.describe())

df['total_sale_Quartile'] = (
    pd.cut(
        df['total_sale'], bins=list(df.total_sale.describe()),
        labels=['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'], include_lowest=True)
)

Comment: We can use `df['total_sale'].quantile([0, .25, .50, .75, 1])`. But if you want to just categorize based on quartiles we can alternatively use `pd.qcut`.